# Exercises on directed acyclic graphs and appropriate controls

Tags: regression, directed-acyclic-graphs, causality

I have recently started my first steps in causal inference and looking to practice further.
Is anyone aware of any good resource that provides examples of directed acyclic graphs and the appropriate regression models for each?